# How to remove www from wp-admin .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wp-admin

currently, I am having an issue when I load my **wp-admin** it will auto redirect to

https://www.www.example.com/wp-admin

I want to remove single www from wp-admin only
is there required any if else condition on `.htaccess` file?

Normal website is working fine.

Here is the .htaccess code

```
# redirect http to https all domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Please help me,

Thanks.

Comment: What's your current `.htaccess` file contents? What values are held in rows #1 and #2 of `wp_options` table in the database?

Comment: go to general setting and check wordpress url and site url is entered correctly.

Comment: @ShankarSBavan in general setting url is correctly entred like "www.example.com"

Comment: can you share your current `.htaccess` file contents?

Comment: @LukaszFormela in option table #1 is www.example.com and #2 is www.example.com

Comment: @PeshrawH.Ahmed here it is

`# redirect http to https all domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: update your question with .htaccess

Comment: Is your site url contains http://

Comment: can you update your .htaccess to this. https://jsfiddle.net/5axp9v1y/#&togetherjs=b65L7nVz1f
sorry about using jsfiddle for .htaccess code. I'm too lazy to find another tool :))

Comment: I'm gonna put it as an answer, if anyone else have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Update your `.htaccess` file to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This code will redirect unsecure connections to secure connections and force `www`